# Alertdialog multiple listeners

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onitemclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I created a Dialog which displays a list of items.

Now I need to also catch long-click events for editing purposes.

How could this be archieved?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.select_a_person);
    final UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(this);
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            selecteduUser = (User) adapter.getItem(which);
            if (selecteduUser != null) {
                mName.setText(selecteduUser.getName());
            }
        } 
    });
    builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently I am seeing two solution

**Option 1:**

create your own custom dialog. create a activity with list view ( or listactivity whatever you prefer) and set it's theme as dialog.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

There you can easily handle list item click. Then while starting this custom dialog activity pass the list data you want to show.

**Option 2:**

set [setOnShowListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnShowListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnShowListener%29) in your alertdialog in your approach. let me edit from your last line of code

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() 
{       
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) 
    {       
        ListView list = ad.getListView();
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                // DO your task
                return true;
            }           
        });     
    }
});
dialog.show();
```